# How to store the content/value of xpath?

Tags: xpath, selenium-ide

Assume xpath as below:

```
xpath : //div[@id='cslGridViewPanelControl']/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div

Last div element contains 'Displaying 1 to 30 of 145300'.
I need to store 'Displaying 1 to 30 of 145300' in some variable by using selenium tool.
```

I tried

```
command    target           value 
 store      xpath           variable1
 echo      ${variable1}
```

It displays as variable1: xpath. But i need variable1: 'Displaying 1 to 30 of 145300'.
Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Try storeText ( locator, variableName )
Then use it ${variableName}
```

Refer [Selenium documentation](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html) for storeText

Comment: @ Saga:Thank U, it works fine. Now i need to parse the text stored in this variable. If the text stored is 'Displaying 1 to 30 of 145300', i need to store only 145300 in another variable. how can i do it ?

Comment: Regex can help you.  Displaying\\s+\\d+\\s+to\\s+\\d+\\s+of\\s+\\d+

Comment: I didn't get u. How can i put it ? Can u be bit clear, please ?

Comment: Assuming that Javascript is used: var str="Displaying 2 to 30 of 145300"; 
var num = str.split(" ").pop();

Answer (score 2):

saga told you how to store that string, as you need to store only 145300, below code will help you

```
store   |  Displaying 1 to 30 of 145300  |  string
store   | 1 |  delimiter
store   | javascript{storedVars['string'].split('of')[storedVars['delimiter']]}  |  result
echo    | ${result}
```