# How to store and echo all ID's of present input fields by XPath in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, firebug, selenium-ide

I am learning Selenium for automation testing and I am going through and trying to build up some test steps for basic account sign up on a website.

The process will involve grabbing all ID's of input fields within a form and then save those ID's to a variable(s) and echo all of those ID's back.

Currently my XPath looks something like:

```
//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' textField')]/descendant::input
```

Which, in Firebug highlights all of the input fields.

Now my question is, how would I go about saving the ID's of those input fields and echoing those back in Selenium for verification/debugging purposes?

I tried getting a better idea from: [How to store the content/value of xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010992/how-to-store-the-content-value-of-xpath), but the only thing echo'd and saved in the temp variables is just the name of the variable I gave it.

(We'll call this variable "AllFormInputIDs")

Any and all help is super appreciated and any tips for more efficient XPath mark-up/code mark-up would be great! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the below process:

1. **Find all the `input` tag elements in the page and store it in a list.**
2. **Iterate through the list, fetch the attribute `id` using [`getAttribute()`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)) method and store it in another Arraylist, say `AllFormInputIDs` as you mentioned.**
3. **Now you can iterate over the list of "AllFormInputIDs" to do any operation you want.**

Below is the **Java code snippet** for the aforementioned process:

```
//Opening firefox driver instance, maximizing and assigining an implicit timeout of 20 seconds.
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//Navigating to the site
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31574046/how-to-store-and-echo-all-ids-of-present-input-fields-by-xpath-in-selenium");

//Fetching all the elements with tag 'input' and putting in a List
List<WebElement> List_Inputs = driver.findElements(By.tagName("input"));

//Creating an ArrayList object
ArrayList<String> AllFormInputIDs = new ArrayList<String>() ;

//Iterating throught the input ids in List_Inputs and fetching the 'id' attribute
//where 'id' value is not an empty string
for(WebElement inputID: List_Inputs){
    if(!inputID.getAttribute("id").equals(""))
        AllFormInputIDs.add(inputID.getAttribute("id"));
}

//Iterating over AllFormInputIDs where the fetched id's of all Input tags are present
//and printing them
int i=1;
for(String id: AllFormInputIDs){
    System.out.println("ID "+(i++)+": "+id);
}
```

Comment: Like I mentioned to Chandan, you both have given great answers, now I am wondering how I can attempt to test and see which is more fitting. I prefer either or for JAVA/Python, I am just new to Selenium as a whole and wondering how I would call or put this as a test step? :)


Again, both of you have given great answers!

Comment: As you have said, you are using Selenium IDE and export the tests in to a language of your choosing, I would suggest to first navigate to the site you are working on, and then export the file in a language, say **Java**. Then, after exporting, you can copy the code from **\\Fetching all the elements with tag 'input' and putting in a List** (comment above) and paste it after the code for navigation to the concerned URL, and execute.. I think that will work.

Comment: Yeah, I am going to go with Java using Eclipse IDE and import the Selenium JAR. I am already in the process now of getting a few prompts from the user (Browser, Website, etc) and letting the driver choose the instance of prompted browser and site to begin with a more friendly UI. 

I am excited for learning JAVA again and building automation tests :)

Comment: Great!! Godspeed @Doodely :)

Answer (score 1):

Once you have found your element(s), you can use `getAttribute` method to retrieve the attached attribute of the element and store it.

Lets say we want to print all `href` links which starts with 'Stack' on this page inside footer:-
python code:

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='footer']//../a[contains(.,'Stack')]"):
            print(element.get_attribute('href'))
```

prints:

> https://stackoverflow.com/
>  https://stackapps.com/
>   https://meta.stackexchange.com/
>  http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

Printing the id of the `Ask Questions` Button

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Ask Question']").get_attribute('id'))
```

> nav-askquestion

Working example of a Python file for the same: [GitHubFile](https://github.com/Chandan-Nayak/stackoverflow-files/blob/master/31574046.py)

Comment: Apologies for being new to this, but how would I go about implementing this into my tests? I ask because the IDE it self seems limited on writing such scripts, unless this is a script I'd have to load in?

I see that it lets me export my current tests into a language of my choosing, I just am unsure of how I can bring in this for-loop as a test step, or call it? :)

Comment: I have updated the answer with a working python file for example, I guess you will have to explore [Selenium webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)

Comment: The Python solution was great, but after a frustrating time of finally getting python and a shell solution setup, I went to Eclipse and JAVA since the selenium jar can be ported right in and I can immediately begin coding.

I will revisit python, but for other reasons. Thank you for the great answer though! :)